# AWS EC2 not running web server on default port

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS setup:
here are the steps i followed to setup a Django web server. ( but its not running on public ip )

1. created AWS instance
2. installed Django 1.6.2
3. created sample app
4. added security group (Inbound Requests) of running instance with HTTP - TCP - 80 - 0.0.0.0/0
5. tried following ways to run server.

   python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

   python manage.py runserver ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000

   python manage.py runserver

but server is not accesible from the Public DNS given by EC2.

NOTE: running micro instance with ubuntu 12.04 (LTS) with virtualenv.

what is missing in the above steps.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
 did the trick.

Comment: Worked for me too :)